# Installed Ubuntu on previous Windows machine with partitioned drive

Tags: installation, partitioning

My machine had Windows installed with a HD partitioned in two parts. One for the System and one for my precious Files.

I've decided to see what's new on Ubuntu 13.04, so I installed it. But when I was installing, I choose the "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" option and setting the LVM option, thinking that it would replace the first partition with Ubuntu and leave the second partition alone.

After that, I realized the mistake I've made. The second partition is lost and now the System has only one whole partition.

Are all my files lost? Is there any way to retrieve them?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the noobiness. I just had no idea what LVM was before setting it.

Comment: This is not related to LVM. This is the expected behavior when one chooses **Replace Windows with Ubuntu** The warning clearly says it will delete everything.

Comment: I agree... I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, if anyone gets on the same situation, I was able to retrieve most of my files with [NTFS GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-products.htm).